# how to return number values based on different user input in android

Tags: java, android, math

I am trying to create an application that returns a score based on user input.

for example if the user has 1000 posts on a specific site it would return 1. i would end it at 10000.

1000 = 1
2000 = 2 etc.

here is what i have so far and thanks. this site is awesome.
for now i just have each entry adding. value1+value2 etc.

```
public class DataIn extends Activity {

EditText editPostCount;
EditText editThanksCount;
EditText editRomCount;
EditText editThemeCount;
EditText editKernelCount;
EditText editTutorialCount;
EditText editYearsJoined;
Button mButton;
TextView results;
Button mButton1;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.data_in);
android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

editPostCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPostCount);
editThanksCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editThanksCount);
editRomCount =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRomThreads);
results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.results);
editThemeCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editThemeCount);
editKernelCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editKernelCount);
editTutorialCount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTutorialCount);
editYearsJoined = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editYearsJoined);

mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.results_button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
         //When the button is clicked, call the calucate method.
         calculate();
        }
});


private void calculate() {
    try {

        Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(editPostCount.getText().toString());
        Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(editThanksCount.getText().toString());
        Double value3 = Double.parseDouble(editRomCount.getText().toString());
        Double value4 = Double.parseDouble(editKernelCount.getText().toString());
        Double value5 = Double.parseDouble(editThemeCount.getText().toString());
        Double value6 = Double.parseDouble(editYearsJoined.getText().toString());
        Double value7 = Double.parseDouble(editTutorialCount.getText().toString());
      //do the calculation

        Double calculatedValue = (value1+value2+value3+value4+value5+value6+value7);
        //set the value to the textView, to display on screen.
        results.setText(calculatedValue.toString());


    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // EditText EtPotential does not contain a valid double
    }

mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear_button);
mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     public void onClick(View v) {

          editPostCount.setText("");
          editThanksCount.setText("");
          editRomCount.setText("");
          editThemeCount.setText("");
          editKernelCount.setText("");
          editTutorialCount.setText("");
          editYearsJoined.setText("");
             results.setText("");}
 });

    }   }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: Look at it... There's lotsa empty lines, the first line, `public class DataIn extends Activity {` and the last line `}` is not a in a code tag, the indentation is all over the place. 4 spaces is what's used for indenting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the score for every value using a simple division, that is cut to an integer.
In this example I also defined one constant to determine for each different value a specific score factor.

```
private static final int TOTALCOUNT_SCOREFACTOR = 1000;

int totalCountScore = totalCount / TOTALCOUNT_SCOREFACTOR;
```

I suggest you not to use doubles, generally int is enough.
I also suggest you to use an array of values, instead of defining all of them separately. In that way, you can easily add or remove values in future.

Comment: not every value would divide by 1000. just the first two. so i would define each integer as needed right?

Comment: Of course, that's why it's clearer if you make more different constants, so you can divide any value by a different divider and keep in the same place all the dividers.

Comment: thank you. how would i tie that in to add together as i have in my post?

Comment: how to you cast a view to those integers?

Comment: What do you mean?
If you want to show the result, try this, in a TextView textView:
textView.setText(Integer.toString(totalCountScore));

Comment: actually i have it. thanks a lot. what about entering two letters to return a score?

Comment: I have four letter sets     rd,rt,rd,erd.   how would i return a number for those?

Comment: There are dozens of way to do this. This is an example:

HashMap<String,Integer> scoreMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>;

private void initScores() {
scoreMap.put("rd",100);
scoreMap.put("erd",200); //...
}

private int getScore(String s) {
   return scoreMap.get(s);
}

PS: please accept the answer if you think so.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not misunderstanding your question, but if you want the score to add 1 point for every 1000 posts, you simply get the number of posts and divide by 1000. for example:

```
//value1 is the post count
int calculatedvalue = value1/1000;
```

So if the number of posts(value1) is 3500, calculatedvalue would be 3.(the remainder is cut off during division)

Comment: thank you for answering. so i could do that for each value right? as some entries will be small numbers like rom count or kernel count.how would i add that to my current method?

Comment: You would define a variable in your method that would keep a running total.  Change the return type of calculate from void to int, and return the running total after it is figured up.  Rather than your function call being "calculate();", it will return a value so your call will look like "score = calculate();"